# Can an employee be forced to go home

Tags: relationships

Can a shift manager send an employee home because the employee told the manager he was not following company policy?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for the reason stated? This will have to depend on the company and the policies/procedures in place (check with HR or equivalent). Otherwise, as a general rule, employees can be asked to go home by managers; yes.

Comment: It's fast food and I never received any handbook. The main boss is a bully himself so there is no one to go to. The shift manager often speaks about following procedures, so when I pointed out that he was not following it himself, he got mad and sent me home.

Comment: Specific to the company and/or the locale so off topic,  voting to close.

Comment: I disagree!  Only your mommy can send you home.  I do think a manager could make you leave the workplace though. :)

Comment: The old saying "you don't have to go home, but you came stay here" comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, yes, the manager can deal summarily with a discipline issue at their discretion.

What happens after is out of the scope of the question, but the employee and/or the manager can take up the issues with higher ups either the same day or later. The employee can either go home, or go to a higher manager and state their case.